# How do i sort by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am new to rails, I have a rails app that allows me to create a deadline by providing a title, date and description and it creates a countdown, the problem is I want to sort all the deadlines by the date entered, how do i do that in my index method?

```
  class DeadlinesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @deadline = current_user.deadlines.new
    end

    def create
        @deadline = current_user.deadlines.new(params[:deadline].permit(:title, :date, :description))
        if @deadline.save
            redirect_to @deadline
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @deadline = current_user.deadlines.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index

        @deadlines = current_user.deadlines.all
        @deadlines = current_user.deadlines.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end

    def update
        @deadline = current_user.deadlines.find(params[:id])

        if @deadline.update(params[:deadline].permit(:title, :date, :description))
            redirect_to @deadline
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @deadline = current_user.deadlines.find(params[:id])
        @deadline.destroy

        redirect_to deadlines_path

    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:deadline).permit(:title, :date, :description)
    end

end
```

deadlines model:

```
    class Deadline < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 8 }


    validates :date, presence: true

    validates :description, presence: true,
                length: { maximum: 230 }

   #validates_format_of :date, :with => /\A[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\z/, :message => "Enter Date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD" 
    belongs_to :user    

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by the date entered"? Put some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@deadlines = current_user.deadlines.order(:date)
                         .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the order method

```
@deadlines = current_user.deadlines.order(:date)
```

You can also specify ascending or descending using,

```
@deadlines = current_user.deadlines.order(date: :asc)  # Ascending
@deadlines = current_user.deadlines.order(date: :desc) # Descending
```